# Storyboard warning: prototype table cells must have reuse identifiers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard

I am getting this warning from storyboard - prototype table cells must have reuse identifiers.

I have renamed the identifier in the attributes inspector but it does not seem to have removed the warning.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You've either filled in the wrong field or you have more than one table view. Can you post a screenshot of the attributes inspector?

Comment: It's ok now mate. I have found a solution. The value for Identifier should be the same as reuse identifier. :)

Comment: Have you set an identifier for every cell?

Comment: Hi Honda! Could you please tell me what you did because i'm getting the same error.

Comment: @Varun Mehta : take a look at my answer ...

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes (currently using latest Xcode 5 Beta 5 (5B103i)) highlights wrong locations of the error/warning in the storyboard. So if you will click on the warning it will sometimes show the wrong location where similar warning could be already fixed. I do suggest manually go through any of tableviews you have in your storyboard and check if there are any other cells with missing identifier. Above solved my issue with this warning. Thanks @K.Honda for asking the question as this topic helped me to understand how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

To shut up the warning you have to give a name to the cell identifier :

[image]

Comment: happned to me to.
close xcode - open it, and then change the identifier

Comment: When the warning remains means that somewhere in your StoryBoard there is still a cell without identifier

Comment: If you have more than 1 prototype cells, you must give them all an indetifier, else just set the number to one in the prototype cell

Comment: I had to delete the Derived Data folder (Xcode equivalent of a Windows Reboot) and rebuild to get rid of this spurious warning.

Comment: This worked for me: close Xcode, open /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData in Finder, and delete all of its contents (not the DerivedData folder itself).

Answer (score 20):

Another way is to set the Table View 'Prototype Cells' property to zero in Attributes Inspector, if you are defining the cell using a .xib programatically.

[image: Setting prototype cells to 0 in Attributes Inspector]

Answer (score 10):

As storyboard is actually XML file, so another trick is to open your storyboard with any text editor (not Xcode!) and try to find all tableViewCell nodes. For example press **CMD+F**, type `<tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill"` and press Enter. You will probably find out, the rows same to this one:

```
<tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="blue" accessoryType="disclosureIndicator" hidesAccessoryWhenEditing="NO" indentationLevel="1" indentationWidth="0.0" reuseIdentifier="GenericCellID" id="kBr-Qn-Tki">
```

Please pay your attention on `reuseIdentifier="GenericCellID"` key value.
The rows which fire the warning (without reuse identifiers) will not have such key value. Look nodes above in your text editor and you will see `tableViewController` node with class name you need to check in Xcode's storyboard editor and fix, according to aleroot' answer.

Comment: You can actually open your storyboard as code with Xcode by doing a CTRL+click on your storyboard file > `Open As` > `Source Code`

Answer (score 4):

If your Xcode warning still doesn't go away even after you have set the reuseIdentifier, then try Menu "Product -> Clean". This helped for me and after that, the warning didn't show up anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Since double-clicking this warning can lead to a bit of a wild goose chase (the specific UITableViewCell doesn't get selected), just wanted to add that while some of these warnings will auto-resolve, **some will not**.

If you are confident you've tagged all your cells in Storyboard, rebuild the project - your warning may disappear (as did mine).

Answer (score 2):

A hail mary: restarting XCode worked for me (but it was probably just a manual rebuild that was required).

Answer (score 1):

I got this warning for Xcode 7. I am working with Swift.
I did not added the navigation controller for the initial view controller. When I did so.. I got this warning from StoryBoard. 
What I did is:

1. There are two segues

   1. from Navigation Controller to Root view Controller and
   2. from Root View controller to your initial View controller.
2. Select the segue connecting the root view controller to the
   initial view controller.
3. Name the identifier
4. Select the "Prototype" written part of the controller--> there
   you will see identifier as an option.
5. Paste the same name of the identifier as entered earlier.

The warning goes.. if not clean the sdk :)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you are setting the **Reuse Identifier** on the object, rather than the **Restoration ID**. Both are available via the storyboard, and easily confused.

In the storyboard XML file you'll want to be setting `reuseIdentifier`, not `restorationIdentifier`.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that this error occurs when you have multiple prototype cells (in the tableview properties) and have not given *all* of them re-use identifiers.

Comment: I've seen this too, is there a way to name all the cells at once or is there another way to remove these warnings?

Comment: Every Prototye cell needs it own unique name. So there is no way to do it automatically

Answer (score 0):

The identifier is the name you refer to in you .m file. When it is not filled it is not possible to reference the cell.

Answer (score 0):

This for setting reuse identifier by programmatically

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"wot";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: someStyle reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

    return cell;
}
```