# Cell missing in the UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using the tab library [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip)

If I don't add this line: `[self.tableView registerClass:[UserInfoBasicCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifierBasicCell];`
 
It crashes at cellForRowAtIndexPath:  `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifierBasicCell forIndexPath:indexPath];`

If I add that line, I can't see the cell. The cell is not programely created, it is created in the storyboard.

The library has a bug: http://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip/issues/10

How to let the cell display? 
Or is there any good alternative for the tab library [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) ?

Comment: you could try [registerNib: forCellReuseIdentifier:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW76) instead

Comment: I had tried that too, but not work.

Comment: where did you add that method ? in viewDidLoad or cellForRowAtIndexPath: ? try [Set reuse identifiers in storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10812806/2673612) instead registerNib ?

Comment: How is the table defined in the storyboard, the cell I'd set there and the class set?

Comment: Make sure that the value of _kCellIdentifierBasicCell_ is same as you are providing in the storyboard for cell reuse identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code at cellForRowAtIndexPath for Custom Cell

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StoryBoardCellIdentifier";

        UserInfoBasicCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil){
            cell = [[UserInfoBasicCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
```

//OR for default UITableView Cell-->Proto Type Cell at storyboard

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"UserInfoBasicCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Hope it helps you..!

Comment: Not work. The Library has a bug:https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip/issues/10