# Unsupported configuration prototype table cells must have reuse identifiers

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I build a `UITableView` in `ViewDidLoad` like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGSize viewSize = self.view.frame.size;
mainScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, viewSize.width, viewSize.height -149)];
[mainScroll setPagingEnabled:YES];
[mainScroll setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[mainScroll setDelegate:self];
[mainScroll setTag:101010];

    // #1
    UIScrollView *scroll1 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, viewSize.width, viewSize.height -149)];
    UITableView *table101 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, viewSize.width, viewSize.height -149) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [table101 setDataSource:self];
    [table101 setDelegate:self];
    [table101 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [table101 setTag:101];
    [table101 setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

    [scroll1 addSubview:table101];

    // #2
    UIScrollView *scroll2 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(viewSize.width, 0, viewSize.width, viewSize.height -149)];
    UITableView *table102 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, viewSize.width, viewSize.height -149) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [table102 setDataSource:self];
    [table102 setDelegate:self];
    [table102 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [table102 setTag:102];
    [table102 setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

    [scroll2 addSubview:table102];

[mainScroll addSubview:scroll1];
[mainScroll addSubview:scroll2];
[mainScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(viewSize.width *2, viewSize.height -149)];



}
```

In `TableViewCell` I used this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15)];

    }

    NSMutableArray *mutableArray;

    if (tableView.tag == 101) {
        mutableArray = self.itemsInTable_Molhaq;

    } else if (tableView.tag == 102) {
        mutableArray = self.itemsInTable_Ziyarah;
    }

    NSString *labelString = [[mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
    NSInteger indentLevel = [[[mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Level"] intValue];

    [cell.textLabel setAttributedText:[self attributeString:labelString indentLevel:indentLevel]];

return cell;

}
```

Everything is working properly, But Xcode shows me this:

```
Unsupported configuration prototype table cells must have reuse identifiers
```

What did I miss? Can I get some help?

Comment: This is storyboard editor's warning. Check your *.storyboard files and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808621/storyboard-warning-prototype-table-cells-must-have-reuse-identifiers)

Comment: May be you are using tableview on storyboard. As according to this code it wont give this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"wot";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (!cell)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: someStyle reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

return cell;
}
```

May be it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear what the error says. You have created a prototype cell in your storyboard and not given it an identifier. Go to the storyboard and look at the properties of the cell. Fill in the identifier.

Comment: I don't have any TableView object in my storyboard, I create all my TableView  in ViewDidLoad, see my code above