# Why am I getting an NSInternalInconsistencyException error on one phone and not on another and not on the simulator?

Tags: nib, collectionview

I get the below error, but inconsistently.  When I deploy my app to one phone, I don't get this error.  When I deploy my app to another phone, I do.  And, when I run the app on the simulator, I don't get the error.

What does this mean, and how do I deal with it?

Error: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier cellId - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I'm pretty sure the error is occurring because of CollectionView, rather than Tableview.

The code for that is:

`override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {`

```
`let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell`
```

In viewDidLoad, I have:

```
`collectionView?.register(VideoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")`
```

Also, this may be relevant:

```
`class VideoCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }`
```

I'm sorry I'm such a noob, but I don't know where the xib file is. I'm not using a storyboard.

Comment: Can you please post your code for the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method?  And please show a screenshot of your storyboard or xib file where you define your "prototype cell".  This answer shows the kind of screenshot I am talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10812806/1461050

Comment: I suspect that this line of code: `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell` is somehow executing *before* this line `collectionView?.register(VideoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")`.  You might set breakpoints on both lines (or add logging) to verify this.  If you can confirm, you then need to move up the code that registers  the cellId so it happens earlier.